# Cannot figure out how to rig a flexible strap

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to rig a long, high-poly rectangle object so that it will be posable/deformable to behave like thick strap or belt. I don't need it for animation, just static renders.

I've created a multi-boned armature and tried adding it to the rectangle as a modifier, but when I then pose the armature the rectangle remains rigid, i.e., nothing changes in the rectangle when I pose the armature bones.

I've successfully employed armatures to pose segmented "hard" objects, but this deformation thing has me baffled. The rectangle mesh is composed of multiple polygons along its length so there are plenty of places for it to "bend".

I've spent several days working on this and have viewed multiple video tutorials and read multiple guides, but in the end I'm just as confused as ever. It appears that there may be several approaches to this, none of which have worked for me yet. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

UPDATE: Here is a screenshot from my project. The chamfered rectangle is currently selected and it is what I want to make flexible, like a strap. Above that are objects that are to be a carabiner that will be articulated and (hopefully) all a part of the same armature. Nothing has been parented to the single armature yet.

I know how to bone the carabiner; what's stumping me is making the chamfered rectangle deformable. One tutorial I saw stated that parenting (Ctrl+P) does not result in deformable meshes.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: could you add a screenshot? Maybe you could use a curve?

Comment: The mesh needs to be bind to the bones and has to have vertex weight groups. If If parenting the mesh to the Armature with Ctrl-P > Automatic Weights doesnt work, you will have to post the blend file so someone can have a look whats wrong

Comment: Yay!! Parenting with Automatic Weights works! Thank you Jerryno!

Comment: @Jerryno Can you write an answer.

Comment: I guess I really don't have an definitive answer yet. What I'm discovering is that Blender offers a variety of solutions to my quest for a posable strap. [Sci Fi Animator](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuGWRbFrq3bZkOEpQ02Xpww) has some great tutorials, including [Make a Curved Armature with Spline IK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJuQBSxUH80).  

I've got a lot to explore here.